# Button with a link works in Firefox but not Chrome or Safari

Tags: css, button, frontend

So I know there a ton of compatability questions on StackOverflow concerning buttons but I couldn't find an answer after several searches. I have a video.html file in my index so the directory isn't a problem; this works in Firefox. But in Chrome or Safari, when I press the button, it adds a ?# to the end of the current url rather than properly redirecting it to video.html.

```
<center><button onclick= "location.href='video.html'"> Create</button>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9nF2/)
CSS

```
.btn
{
    background-color: rgb(7, 55, 99);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px 12px 3px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

HTML

```
<center><a href="video.html" class="btn">Create</a></center>
```

Comment: K.I.S.S. ; Mess around with the css. I suggest [Button Maker](http://www.cssbutton.me/calebogden/4fea3b663f2df0b92500000d)

Comment: @Pawan this is what I was saying, while buttons can be tweaked (just about anything can) they are for form submissions and executing js functions, NOT navigation. Using JS to execute this is pointless and simply adds more lines of code to perform a very basic task.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<center><button onclick="window.location.href='video.html'"> Create</button>`

If that doesn't work it looks like there is a space between your onclick attribute and the first quotation, this might be causing your parsing error in webkit.

PS - Is there a reason you are using a button tag? Since all you are doing is navigating to another page you should just use an anchor tag and style it with CSS. Then you will have a more solid, semantic solution.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents worth

```
<script>
function video_redirect(video)
{
 top.location.href = video;
}
</script>

<center><button onclick="video_redirect('video.html')"> Create</button>
```

or just use a hyperlink over the button...

```
<center><a href="video.html"><button> Create</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used to some **method for blank parent top**

```
For self:
location.href="video.html";

For blank:
window.open="video.html";

For parent:
parent.location.href="video.html";

For top:
top.location.href="video.html";

For SomeFrame:
parent.SomeFrame.location.href="video.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks ok and works fine for me in Chrome, FF and MSIE. Your problem lies most likely somewhere else. Maybe some JS lib is catching all button events? Try isolating the even entirely, i.e. load just that single line of code into your browser and see if that works. If it doesn't it's your local machine.

Comment: But he said this is working correctly in Firefox which sounds like a parsing issue.